# ArcPy: Delete field loop with if exception

Tags: arcpy, loop

Am new to ArcPy , am trying to join the same features from different geodatabase but I don't need all of attributes, so want to make a loop to find each feature class and delete the fields I don't want so I can apply other code to see the differences in some fields as QC.
Main problem is in getting the field name and apply in if statements

NOTE I TOOK THIS WAY BECAUSE I HAVE A LOT OF LAYERS AND Join by spatial tool failed to join all the fields because they are a lot , because I tried after delete some it works as a model or batch, but I can't do it for all.

> Error : Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 14)

this is the :

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = " C:/sample.gdb"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []
for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
         path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
         fields = arcpy.ListFields(path)
         arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass)
         for field in fields:
         keep = f.name
         if keep <> ['verify_status','MODIFIED_BY','CREATED_BY']:
         arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, f.name)
         else:
         print("cant delete {}".format(f.name))
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Are you getting error messages, if so what are they?

Comment: Thanks for your replay , this is the message Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 14)

Comment: Yes looking at your code you do not have correct indentation after your 'for' line. You just need to correct that. Look at examples of correct indentation.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to outline here:

- As @Hornbydd mentioned, your indentation after the `for` loop is messed up. Everything after that loop should be indented, as well as the lines after the `if` and `else` statements.
- Indentation has to be a multiple of four always (each indentation block corresponds to four spaces). For example, your current indentation from lines 10 to 13 have 9 spaces indentation when it should be 8.
- The `<>` operator is deprecated. Use `!=` instead.
- You don't have any variable named `f`. I am assuming you are referring to each field so change `f` to `field`.

Your code could look something like this after taking this considerations into account:

```py
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = " C:/sample.gdb"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []
for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        fields = arcpy.ListFields(path)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass)
        for field in fields:
            keep = field.name
            if keep != ['verify_status','MODIFIED_BY','CREATED_BY']:
                arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, field.name)
            else:
                print("cant delete {}".format(field.name))
```

One important thing to note is that `inFeatures` and `outFeatureClass` are not defined either. I can't help you with that but I am sure you will figure it out.

Furthermore, you'll probably want to check [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for this kind of issues in the future as these issues are rather programming/Python related and do not have any specific relation with GIS.